# Invoke bamboo plan variables in a python script under script task

Tags: python, bamboo

I have a simple script task added to my Bamboo plan which is inline Python script.

```
/usr/bin/python <<EOF
print "Hello"
EOF
```

It works just fine.

Now I want to just pass Hello as a plan specific variable so I configured a variable called pythontest within bamboo plan variables and provided it the value Hello.

When I switch the script to:-

```
/usr/bin/python <<EOF
print "$bamboo_pythontest"
EOF
```

It does nothing.

After going through below post:-

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bamboo-questions/How-I-can-access-global-and-or-plan-specific-variables-from/qaq-p/162809

```
/usr/bin/python <<EOF
import os
print os.environ['bamboo_pythontest]
EOF
```

I get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: ''
```

Is there a way to successfully invoke Bamboo plan variables within a Python inline script just like it works for a shell or batch script.
Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Ashley

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into a solution where we can run the python code from inside bamboo. The error that you are pointing, looks to be syntax error. Try this.

`/usr/bin/python <<EOF
print("Hello World")
EOF`